# How to upload a file using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

It's a button tag and I'm trying with below code:

```
element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Browse']")  
element.send_keys('//Users//test//Desktop//Auto//AutomationDownloads//IonicSamlAssertion.xml')
```

Comment: So what is your exact Question? Why don't you invoke the `click()` method next? Are you seeing any error? What does the error says? Update the question with relevant HTML and the error stack trace.

Comment: What is the issue

Comment: The file is not getting uploaded

Comment: It's probably because you are using two forward slash. Either use a single slash `/Users/...` or escape the backslash: `\\Users\\...`.

Comment: <button class="buttonWhite" type="button" style="width: 57px; height: 24px;">Browse</button>
<span class="GLL3A2SDHIB">No .XML file selected</span>  This is the html code. And the error is Stacktrace:
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///var/folders/sr/j08l1z9d79q231g39hwkdhk572412c/T/tmpWh6dt_/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10271)
    at fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify (file:///var/folders/sr/j08l1z9d79q231g39hwkdhk572412c/T/tmpWh6dt_/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:603)

Answer (score 0):

You are sending keys to a button, that will not work. If you have an input field with type 'file' you can send the keys to that input field and submit the form, for example:

```
element = self.driver.find_element_by_id("inputFile");
element.send_keys('//Users//test//Desktop//Auto//AutomationDownloads//IonicSamlAssertion.xml');
```

After that, you can submit the form

Comment: Do have any idea how to upload for a button ?

Comment: Can you post some of the html? I will check for you

Comment: <button class="buttonWhite" type="button" style="width: 57px; height: 24px;">Browse</button> <span class="GLL3A2SDHIB">No .XML file selected</span> This is the html code.

Comment: Is it inside a form tag?